# Flutter Can't Convert String To Double

Tags: json, api, flutter, parsing

Hello everyone i have a simple function that will receive double from my server and then it should parse this decimal to double and add it to the total amount variable

```
            for (int i = 0; i < purchase.length; i++){
              currentTotalPrice = currentTotalPrice + purchase[i]['total_price'];
            }
```

the thing is i am receiving the total price which is a decimal in the database in a String format and when i try to do something like `(purchase[i]['total_price']).toDouble();` the compiler throws

```
Class 'String' has no instance method 'toDouble'.
Receiver: "15.00"
Tried calling: toDouble()
```

i don't know why in other parts of my code it worked correctly

this is how i am receiving the data

```
Future<List> _fetchPurchases() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String accessToken = prefs.getString("accessToken");

  final response = await http.get(
    '$webSiteUrl/api/admin/purchases/${article['id']}/$_billNumber',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
    },
  );
  if(response.statusCode == 200){
    List purchases = json.decode(response.body);
    return purchases;
  }else{
    return showErrorMessage(context);
  }
}
```

Note: I am Aware of the Constructor solution where you create a class and then factory the data to custom dart object but for some circumstances i can't do that unless i refactor a very large part of the code so if there is a direct way like `toDouble()` method it would be the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed `toDouble` does not exist in the `String` class, but if you must use it, you can create an extension and import it, something like this

```
extension NumberParsing on String {
  double toDouble() {
    return double.parse(this);
  }
}
```

check this gist https://gist.github.com/fcontreras/d5095da7daa0ce24e0f3cb157b91e97f

Comment: basically its double.parse() method , anyways i tried doing it directly and it worked correctly i don't know why but yesterday it didn't ^_*